# Display Sorted content from strings VBS

Tags: vbscript, hta

I need a command to display particular from the result of the execution of cmd argument in vbs. I've the code as

```
    <script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">
    set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strOut=""
    sub start
    cmdarg="%comspec% /c netsh wlan show hosted " 
    set objExCmd = objShell.Exec(cmdarg)
    strOut=objExCmd.StdOut.ReadAll
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = "[\f\n\r\v]+"
    regEx.Global = True
    regEx.Multiline = True
    strOut = regEx.Replace(strOut, "<br>")
    TraceOut.innerHTML= strOut
    end sub
    </script>
```

This list all output after execution as below:

### Hosted network settings

```
Mode                   : Allowed
SSID name              : "MyWiFi"
Max number of clients  : 10
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
```

### Hosted network status

```
Status                 : Not started
```

I need to display only SSID name. Ie, "MyWiFi"
It changes whenever i change ssid name. So it is not always "MyWiFi"

This is the complete HTA program

```
    <head><title>Hosted Network</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA";
      APPLICATIONNAME="Hosted Network";
      BORDER="thin";
      BORDERSTYLE="normal";
      SINGLEINSTANCE="no";
    >
    </head><body bgcolor="#E8E8E8" >
    <script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">
    sub subfn
    set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    cmdarg="%comspec% /c netsh wlan show hosted"
    set strOut = objShell.Exec(cmdarg)
    Dim re : Set re = New RegExp
    re.Multiline = True
    re.Pattern   = "^SSID\s+name\s+:\s+""([^""]+)"""
    strOut = "SSID: >" & re.Execute(strOut)(0).Submatches(0) & "<"
    TraceOut.innerHTML= strOut
    end sub
    </script>
    <input type="Button" name="B1" value="Find"  onclick="subfn">
    <div id=TraceOut></div></body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a RegExp with a capture/group/submatch to cut the desired info from the netsh output:

```
  Dim strOut : strOut = Join(Array( _
      "Mode                   : Allowed" _
    , "SSID name              : ""MyWiFi""" _
    , "Max number of clients  : 10" _
  ), vbCrLf)
  WScript.Echo strOut
  Dim re : Set re = New RegExp
  re.Multiline = True
  re.Pattern   = "^SSID\s+name\s+:\s+""([^""]+)"""
  WScript.Echo "SSID: >" & re.Execute(strOut)(0).Submatches(0) & "<"
```

output:

```
Mode                   : Allowed
SSID name              : "MyWiFi"
Max number of clients  : 10
SSID: >MyWiFi<
```

(But I don't see how 'sorted' is part of your problem)

Comment: Thank you Ekkehard. I made changes according to your suggestion and the complete code is updated in the question above. I'm juss a beginner in this.
My program gives me the error "Type mismatch re.Execute" 
How to solve this? I want to get SSID using this application.
Also WScript.Echo is not working.